# Fetch all Folders from root directories in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to fetch all the folder from internal and external storage same as any other video player app , how to make it done in flutter for both IOS/Android

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ext_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage) like this,

```
void getRootPath() async {
  var path = await ExtStorage.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  print(path);  // /storage/emulated/0
}
```

and can search iterable.